# c# facebook api: Facebook private messages RunTimeBinderException

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My Goal:

To retrieve your own messages and to let the user answer it in my c# application.

Code:

```
 var client = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);

        dynamic result = client.Get("me/inbox",null);

        foreach (dynamic item in result.inbox.data)
        {

            if (item.unread > 0 || item.unseen > 0)
            {
                string conversationID = item.id;
                string otherPerson = item.to.data[1].name;//the item.to.data[0] its myself


                foreach (dynamic message in item.comments.data)
                {
                    //Do want you want with the messages
                    string id = message.id;
                    string fromName = message.from.name;
                    string fromID = message.from.id;
                    string text = message.message;
                    string createdDate = message.created_time;
                }

                //To send a message in this conversation, just
                dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
                parameters.message = "Automatic generated message of messenger app!";
                MessageBox.Show(conversationID);


                break;
            }
        }
```

At this moment I just want to retrieve an ID so later I can get the data message out of it.

Problem:

*RunTimeBinderException was unhandled (cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference)**
http://prntscr.com/1wnikm

My account has 1 chat message he didn't saw yet but it gets stuck when I run it.